# Why are we getting yearling badges for a site that is 1 day old?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, yearling-badge

The title says it all, why are we getting yearling badges on MSO for a site that is 1 day old?

Comment: ... because meta.

Comment: @hichris123 comments are not for answers, please post it as one :D

Comment: @OneKitten I was going to post an answer... but then I got busy. :(

Comment: Why don't I have one yet :(

Comment: I don't know about you, but I feel like I've always been here.

Comment: @djechlin: you don't belong here. *Go away.*

Comment: @OneKitten flagged as offensive? :P

Comment: As long as it doesn't bother me all day with repeated notifications it doesn't really meta to me.

Comment: @hichris123 I was gonna post an answer, but [then...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeYsTmIzjkw).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Because the badge fairy is granting you extra badges.

[image]

Enjoy.

<sub>Technically this site has always existed.  It's just been broken off from MSE, which has also always existed.  Something something Eastasia.</sub>

Comment: I get it now. My account was created almost 3 years ago, and I visted the site on one day. The day the account was created. Which is today. Which is 3 years ago. How could I miss that?

Comment: +1 because I like the idea that Kevin Montrose is a big tinkerbell fan. No particular reason to like that. I just do.

Comment: +1 **meta.SO** has _always_ been at war with **meta.SE**.

Comment: If we didn't have timestamps I'd insist this was the inspiration for [Friday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfVsfOSbJY0).

Comment: I've got 5 and counting this afternoon. One .. at .. a ... time. So I keep thinking "Oh, this time I must have a real notification"; Badge-rolled again. Is this badge fairy also like Tinkerbelle in that if I quit believing in her, she'll go away?

Comment: ...guess not. Make that **6** now.

Comment: @T.E.D. Which site are these badges awarded for?

Comment: @T.E.D. you are a long time user with a profile creation date of 6 years ago based on the creation date of your Stack Overflow profile.  You shouldn't receive any more but enjoy those badges!

Answer (score 15):

Your meta.SO account is linked to your SO account, just like all other child meta sites, therefore, it is technically (supposed to be) as old as your SO account. This is just a side effect of the split.

But I like the alternate theory better: "because meta." ;)

Comment: And I'm not sure it's *that* linked, on other metas yearling badges are independent, and so is the first/last access dates, days visited etc.

Comment: "Because meta" explains it better :)

Comment: Meta, because meta - meta.

Answer (score 9):

You are correct - a child account of the parent site (in this case stackoverflow.com) is copied and badge grants will run as if you created the account the day you signed up for stackoverflow.com.

BTW - Kevin wins this time..

Comment: *I* was wrong, Doorknob and OneKitten were right.

Answer (score 8):

Because the yearling badge has been retroactively applied to your SO account, as you would have got an account together with your SO account if the standard child meta was used.

Comment: In this case, I should get more of those.

Comment: @bfavaretto Caching, always caching. Wait a few minutes.

Comment: @bfavaretto: I got one each hour until I reached the five that were "owed" me.